# Can't make SELinux context types permanent with semanage

Tags: rhel6, selinux

I created a new folder at /modevasive to hold my mod_evasive scripts and for the Log Directory. I'm trying to change the context type to httpd_sys_content_t so Apache can write to the folder. I did `semanage fcontext -a -t "httpd_sys_content_t" /modevasive` to change the context and then `restorecon -v /modevasive` to enable the change, but restorecon didn't do anything. So I used `chcon` to change it manually, did the restorecon to see what would happen and it changed it back to default_t.

semanage fcontext -l gives:

```
/modevasive/          all files          system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0`
```

And looking at `/etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts.local` gives

```
 /modevasive/    system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0
```

So why does restorecon keep setting it back to default_t?

Comment: FWIW I can't get this to happen, for me it works as expected. What does `matchpathcon /modevasive` say ?

Comment: /modevasive    system_u:object_r:default_t:s0

Comment: That explains why it's being reset to default_t by restorecon, hopefully @michaelhampton  will cruise by and explain why there is a difference soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I reached out to RedHat support and this was the answer I got.

He had me do the same steps, except for in the first semanage command, he has me do `"/modevasive(/.*)?"`  instead of just `"/modevasive"`. I haven't got an explanation why, but that solved the problem for me.

Comment: The pattern given is not a directory, but a regex match for a pathname. So `/modevasive` would never match anything.

Comment: When you use the restorecon command you need to put a slash and asterisk after the directory name to effect the files within it.  I had to do `restorecon -v /mydir` to effect the directory and `restorecon -v /mydir/*` to effect its contents (not sure if that's recursive though).